# Qt:exe file not running

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qt5, mingw32, libstdc++

I started using Qt 5.1 with MinGW on Windows 7. I use QtCreator to create the application in debug mode. When I run the exe of any application as a standalone it shows the following error...how ever the same application runs smoothly when I open QtCreator IDE and run it ...I tried setting the environment variable PATH to the bin of the QTCreator and MinGW bin (which QtCreator uses) I am new to this windows environment and MinGW.. any suggestions are welcome...

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is related to the fact that the dynamic linker is not able to find the correct libraries you built your executable with? Try to place all the needed libs into the same dir with the executable and then run it.

If you need to know what are all the needed libs you probably can use dependency walker or ldd from cygwin.

Answer (score 0):

Open command prompt

i.           Click Start

ii.         click All Programs

iii.       click Accessories , right-click Command Prompt

iv.        And then click Run as administrator.

v.          If you are prompted for an administrator password or for a confirmation, type the password, or click Allow or Continue.

vi.        At the prompt, type sfc /scannow and hit enter. Once the scan is complete, restart the computer for the changes to take effect

Comment: @bitguider..tried the above...no result...still the same error message